# Pyspark Dataframe Join using UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a custom join for two dataframes (df1 and df2) in PySpark (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132533/custom-join-with-non-equal-keys)), with code that looks like this:

```
my_join_udf = udf(lambda x, y: isJoin(x, y), BooleanType())
my_join_df = df1.join(df2, my_join_udf(df1.col_a, df2.col_b))
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid PythonUDF PythonUDF#<lambda>(col_a#17,col_b#0), requires attributes from more than one child
```

Is there a way to write a PySpark UDF that can process columns from two separate dataframes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Spark 2.2+**

You have to use [`crossJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=crossjoin#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin) or enable cross joins [in the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38999140/1560062):

```
df1.crossJoin(df2).where(my_join_udf(df1.col_a, df2.col_b))
```

**Spark 2.0, 2.1**

Method shown below doesn't work anymore in Spark 2.x. See [SPARK-19728](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19728).

**Spark 1.x**

Theoretically you can join and filter:

```
df1.join(df2).where(my_join_udf(df1.col_a, df2.col_b))
```

but in general you shouldn't to it all. Any type of `join` which is not based on equality requires a full Cartesian product (same as the answer) which is rarely acceptable (see also [Why using a UDF in a SQL query leads to cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32952080/1560062)).